# What is the best way to play a feedback tap sound in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want the buttons in my app to play a short feedback sound like the rest of the UI elements in the phone.

I think I could add Ext.Audio component but it might be too much overhead just to play a feedback sound.